# How can I upgrade Stripe to 3D-Secure on Sylius?

Tags: stripe-payments, upgrade, sylius, payum

Well, all is in the title.

I have a Sylius website which works fine with Stripe but I have to upgrade the Stripe implementation to be ok with 3D-Secure obligations.

Well, as Stripe is already installed when generating a Sylius project, I can't figure out how to do.

I get the Stripe documentation but where do I make changes in Sylius ? Stripe Bundle ? Payum Bundle ?

Can anyone help me with this ?

Regards.

Comment: Maybe start from here https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/cookbook/payments/stripe.html `stripe-php` is Stripe's official PHP binding that could be used to call Stripe API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a proper question for stack overflow, please read the guidelines.

The current implementation of Stripe on Sylius doesn't support 3D secure which is why it has been depreciated. You might want to check Combodo's Sylius Stripe plugin I got it working in my current 1.7 project but that uses Stripe Checkout not Stripe JS, for Stripe JS you are gonna need your own implementation. There are leads for you on that github issue: https://github.com/Payum/Payum/issues/804, maybe @lolmx solution would help get you going.

Update: I've implemented @lolmx solution in my project, it does take some work but it works.